# Exclude certain groups/modules from mapbox-sdk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mapbox-android

So I'm using the mapbox-sdk for android in my project to display the map with a particular customer's location. However, simply adding mapbox has made my app extremely bulky, and I want to reduce its size by somehow excluding some of the groups/modules from mapbox in the gradle. But I don't know which ones to exclude since I don't know how to get a list of them.
Is there any way to get a list of groups/modules that are automatically integrated with the integration of the mapbox sdk? Which ones should I specifically exclude?

This is the sdk that I'm using:

```
implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.1') {
        transitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use latest mapbox.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.0'
}
```

you can use exclude group like below, to remove certain dependencies:

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.0'){
    exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
}
```

Run 'gradlew :app:dependencies' in your command line will print a list of dependencies.

It will show list of modules in mapbox. try excluding one or more modules as

[image]
     implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-sdk-turf'
        }

ReRun 'gradlew :app:dependencies' in your command line will print a list of dependencies, you will see that excluded library is not in list.

Note: also use 'transitive = false' if you don't want transitive dependency to be considered for dependency resolution.