# Problem with migration from mapbox-sdk version 6.7.0 to 7.3.2, mapbox-core 0.2.0 to 1.3 and mapbox-navigation 0.18.0 to 0.36.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am trying to migrate from my mapbox libraries for android to newer version respectively:

- mapbox-android-sdk from 6.7.0 to 7.3.2,
- mapbox-android-core from 0.2.0 to 1.3.0,
- mapbox-android-navigation from 0.18.0 to 0.36.0,
- mapbox-android-navigation-ui from 0.18.0 to 0.36.0.

However, when I synchronize newer version, the following error appears in build section:

> Error: 
>       Android resource linking failed
>       Output: 
>       D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ojcow\app\build\intermediates\incremental\
>       mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: 
>       error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>       D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ojcow\app\build\intermediates\incremental\
>       mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: 
>       error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>       D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ojcow\app\build\intermediates\incremental\
>       mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1344: 
>       error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>       D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ojcow\app\build\intermediates\incremental\
>       mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1345:
>       error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>       error: failed linking references.

**How can I fix it?**

Here is part of `build.gradle` with the implementation of dependencies

```
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.2'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.36.0'
    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.36.0') 
    {
        transitive = true
    }
```

and maven declaration:

```
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
```

Sdk compile version is `27`
I am working on Android Studio `3.2.1`.

Comment: Have you seen the migration guide> https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Android-6.x-to-7.x-migration-guide

Comment: No, I missed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest mapbox.

```
 repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
      implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.0'
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55618939/4181904

Comment: I'm trying but it doesn't sync. Still problems with references.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for problem with upgrade of libraries was:

- upgrading Android Studio to version `3.4.2`,
- changing the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to version 28.